# Как найти медиану нескольких списков чисел?

Tags: python

```
for i in range(int(input())):
    a = list(map(int, input().split()))
```

например на вход подается число 3 и мы 3 раза в строку вводим список чисел через пробел

а как потом среди получившихся списков найти их медиану, т.е. медиану чисел из всех наборов?

я думаю можно было бы создать один какой-нибудь перед циклом и туда добавлять каждый записанный в цикле, но тогда получится уже матрица(список в списке) и дальше мне кажется сложнее только будет вычислять

Comment: Слить все 3 в один и отсорировать?

Comment: А что мешает запихнуть все числа в один список? `a.extend(map(int, input().split()))`

Comment: *>а как потом среди получившихся списков найти их медиану, т.е. медиану чисел из всех наборов?* - `statistics.median(chain.from_iterable(your_list))`

Comment: @avp да........................

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
nums = []
for i in range(int(input())):
    nums.extend(map(int, input().split()))
nums.sort()
n_len = len(nums)
medi =  nums[n_len//2] if n_len%2 else (nums[n_len//2-1] + nums[n_len//2]) / 2
print(medi)
```